# Simulate different grounds with noise in LTSpice?

Tags: ltspice, noise, ground, signal-to-noise

Is there any way to split 2 different grounds in LTSpice?
What my aim is to observe the optocoupler input side called "GND-D" and collector output side that called "GND-A"; I want to add the noise on the input side (GND-D) so that I can observe the impact on "GND-A" signals.

Comment: what is the part number that you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LTSpice, the ground is simply the reference point for the voltage probe function.  Since the program has the ability to measure differential voltage, you can simply not connect directly to the ground symbol for your ground "A".  You can't let it completely float; you'll need to tie it to ground "D" through a very high impedance (maybe 100 Megaohm) to make the program happy, but this should be high enough to have a negligible effect on your result.

Comment: Thanks, it's work!